# Getting the SMTP server and host from the system configuration in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, email

In Windows you can configure the mail settings from the control panel. What I want to know is where is that information stored? I need to write an app that can send email and by default I want to use those settings. I assumed that if I used the parameterless constructor of SmtpClient it would read them, however when I run the following code:

```
        var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        var host = smtp.Host;
        var port = smtp.Port;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", host,port);
```

I get the host as null (though the port is 25.) If I send a message through it, it throws an exception saying "Host not specified".

Where can I get this pre-configured data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property first before checking for its value otherwise it will be null. However, by default, the port is 25. That's why you see 25 for port even though none was specified. Here's the definition of Host property of SmtpClient object.

```
    public string Host { set; get; }
        Member of System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

    Summary:
    Gets or sets the name or IP address of the host used for SMTP transactions.

    Returns:
    A System.Strin

g that contains the name or IP address of the computer to use for SMTP transactions.
```

Try this...

```
    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "localhost"; //your mail server host name or ip address
    var host = smtp.Host;
    var port = smtp.Port;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", host,port);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I know how to send email when I know the SMTP server. My question was how to get the smtp host that the user has configured via the control panel or via Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would need the SMTP server name before hand and use this info as part of your configuration in your program. You can have the user obtains this information from outlook settings. I assuming you already know this. For whatever reasons you want to get the SMTP server name dynamically, this activity may be viewed as hacking and can pose a security issue to the user. Can you image if some programs automatically use your mail server pre-configured in outlook to send our some emails?

With that said, one way to achieve this is to have a 3rd party port scanner as part of your process to get a list of potential SMTP server names and use the helo command to verify SMTP existence. This should help determine which ip is the SMTP server.